# Single product free ecommerce CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, shopping-cart

Are there any free ready solutions for a simple one-page ecommerce site selling only one product? 
Like this one: http://www.brown-leather-belts.co.uk

Updated:
I don't want to use any third-party checkout systems like paypal or google. My customers will pay cash on delivery. So I just want to receive e-mail with customer's credentials.

Comment: shopify.com springs to mind although I've never used it myself

Comment: for the one you have mentioned, you even need not to use any e-commerce solution at all

Comment: Alex, thanks for a suggestion, but right now I don't want to pay for their service

Comment: I think he means, you're not asking for customers to actually buy anything. You want them to fill out a form that emails you with their name, contact info (probably) and the product name. You don't actually want them to pay for it. Look for a form service instead. Or maybe use something like Drupal with the Webform module to just build a clever little form.

Comment: A simple form that sends the necessary information as a mail to you is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one mentioned in your post has done as little as possible and there is no need to add any heavy duty e-commerce platform/framework until unless you really want to have a full e-commerce portal.

The example has been created by just making a simple HTML form with one product and they have integrated it with pay-pal to payment option, when you want your user to go to payment gateway (paypal in the example), all you need to pass certain parameters (hidden form fields) to the payment gateway to work perfectly.Here are what has been used in the your mention use-case

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@timhardy.com" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="The Broadway Leather Belt" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="60.00" />
  <input type="hidden" value="http://www.timhardy.com/thankyou.php" name="return" />
  <input id="qty-required" type="hidden" name="on1" maxlength="2" value="1" />
   // some other data not hidden fields
</form>
```

This is pretty standard way to communicate with payment gateway and you can find more information about structuring your form by referring the documentation of your payment provider.
For your use-case this is all you have to do

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

One-page ecommerce site? maybe you don't need to use any CMS, just write a simple html page

If you want to use a CMS I suggest Drupal based on you requirement